# Why no products displayed on my web after adding categories and products?

Tags: url

Why no products  displayed  on my web after adding categories and products?
I have added  categories and products  on the backend of magento.
[image]

Is the url wrong?

Comment: rebuild the indexes. System->index management

Comment: Did you select to show the category in the top nav? and is your category is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to reindex your website by going to System>Index Management then select all and Reindex Data